# Structure for a Questions - Answers Collections

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database

I'm not proficient in MongoDB and I have short question. What is the best structure for Questions - Answers Collections. Should I **separate** them to different collections or **keep Answers as a property** of Question? To give you more details:

1. Each question can have many Answers
2. I don't need to search in Answers
3. I will search in Questions
4. Each Answer will have `userId`, `votes` and of course `answer` properties
5. After finding Question, I will be able to expand Answers list and vote for the Answer
6. Questions will be also votable

It will be something like stackoverflow but much simpler. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you won't need to search through answers at all? Let's say I click on a particular user's profile... will I be able to see the questions and answers they've submitted (like stackoverflow)? If so, then it may be necessary to search through the answers to retrieve the answers that a particular user has submitted.

Comment: Hmm maybe in the future, it's hard to predict. For now I don't suppose to do that. However is there any guide about if I should keep Collection separately or as an Array property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep them in two separated collections. As you said you have to be able to query in the questions collection so make a questions collection, you only have to show up answers realted for a specific selected question but will have some specific fields as you mentioned like votes. If we think about stackoverflow for example, you see the questions : click on the question --> then you can query an answers collection for the answer related to that question, also for answers you can have comments which if you not expect insane much of them can kept in a list along with the answer.You can keep the answers of the questions in a collection with a reference and an index on the question id.

Something like his one:

questions:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52205df3d6c893638bc2aa14"),
    "q" : "What is hip?",
    "v" : 1000
}
```

answers :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52205e72d6c893638bc2aa15"),
    "q_id" : ObjectId("52205df3d6c893638bc2aa14"),
    "a" : "Tell me, tell me!",
       "u" : "uid",
    "v" : 153,
    "c" : [
        {
            "c" : "Cool",
            "u" : "uid",
            "v" : 100
        }
    ]
}
```